# Retrieving data from related tables cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have two tables, photos and users. Each user should be able to add multiple images thus the 'photos' table has a user_id field, here is my User model:

```
class User extends AppModel {

     public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $hasOne = array('Product');

    public $hasMany = array('Children'=>array(
    'className'=>'User',
    'foreignKey'=>'parent_id'
    ),


    'Image'=>array(
    'className'=>'Image',
    'foreignKey'=>'user_id'
    ));
```

This is my Image model:

```
    class Image extends AppModel  {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $BelongsTo = array('User');
}
```

And this is my UsersController:

```
    public function listings()  {

    $listings = $this->User->find('all', array(
                                   'contain' => array(
                                          'Image'

                                        )
                                 )
                            );

    $this->set('listings', $listings);
}
```

Each image in the images table has an url field, so thats images.url. What I want to do is retrieve all the url from this table to the users/listing view.

The code above gives the error:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table
>   'Photo'

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Change `public $BelongsTo = 'User';` to `public $belongsTo = array('User');` (not saying it will resolve your problem)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here - `'fields' => array('User.*', 'Photo.*'),` . You asked for Photo fields but its not available on users tables...

Try this-

```
 $listings = $this->User->find('all', array(
                                       'contain' => array(
                                              'Photo'
                                            )
                                     )
                                );
```

And what already Nunser suggested... Change `public $BelongsTo = 'User';` to `public $belongsTo = array('User');`

Comment: With that I am able to retrieve information from the Users table, however while trying to access information from the images table I get undefined index

Comment: What actually the  name of your table is images or photos??

Comment: Sorry, I had changed the table name from Photos to images to make it a bit easier to understand, after I did so i changed all the model names in the controller and models. I modified your code from "Photo" to "Image", it doesnt affect anything really, just a global name change

Comment: do you enabled Containable behavior on you model?? What simple `$this->User->find('all');` is returning without using `contain`? If $this->User->find('all') not fetching Image, that mean there is problem with your model association.... If it is, then update your question with all your real code...

Comment: I enabled containable, I modified the code above to include the code you added. A regular find() does not return the images... The relations between the models are listed in the code.. i am not sure what the problem is

Comment: You said that `undefined index` on first comments?? What your debug($listings) showing??

Comment: my debug


(int) 43 => array(
  'User' => array(
   'password' => '*****',
   'id' => '534363',
   'parent_id' => null,
   'created' => '2014-04-23 00:48:27',
   'modified' => '2014-04-23 00:52:01',
   'lastlogin' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
   'first_name' => 'ddd',
   'last_name' => 'ddd',
   'middle_name' => 'dddd',
   'email' => 'herrhorace@gmail.com',
   'phone' => '0',
   'country' => '',
   'username' => 'antonio',
   'activation_code' => '',
   'status' => false,
   'password_reset' => '',
   'role' => 'manager'
  ),
  'Image' => array()

Comment: You see, its containing `Image` with empty value.. Ensure the user(534363) has entry on `images` table...

Comment: Some of the entries had the user_id from the user that added the image(think thats because most were added before I was fully able to save the user_id), however I am still unable to retrieve the image for these that displays the user_id, here is the result for one of these:

Comment: (int) 7 => array(
  'User' => array(
   'password' => '*****',
   'id' => '534326',
   'parent_id' => '0',
   'created' => '2014-04-16 16:51:27',
   'modified' => '2014-04-16 16:51:27',
   'lastlogin' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
   'first_name' => 'Hor4324682',
   'last_name' => 'ffff',
   'middle_name' => 'Washington',
   'email' => 'herrhorace1@gmail.com',
   'phone' => '0',
   'country' => '',
   'username' => 'reniva',
   'activation_code' => '',
   'status' => false,
   'password_reset' => '',
   'role' => 'artiste'
  ),

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51371/discussion-between-horace-mozadegh-khorampast-cun-and-fazal-rasel)

Comment: If you get the `Image` then just echo the url by $this->Html->image();